# Custom Implementation of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

I don't like the Code-First-approach and want to make use of the new Identity-Features with my EF-mapped classes. I've got a table User with the columns

- Id (bigint, ai, pk)
- Login (nvarchar)
- Password (nvarchar)

The Interface Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser enforces 2 properties:

- Id (string)
- UserName (string)

What, if I don't want to use this structure but I also want to do identity the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that starting with ASP.NET Identity 2 (still in prerelease) you can do:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser<long>
```

Its a little bit more than that when it comes to real life. I blogged about it at [codingfreaks](http://www.codingfreaks.de/?p=2275) (German) and added an English Screencast at [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM). You can find some good hints [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/09/customization-options-with-asp-net-identity.aspx).

So, it is possible.

Comment: i am also having my own tables whether need to include all the columns from asp.net identity table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929767/asp-net-identity-entity-framework-database-first-approach-with-own-table-definti